# Why isn't there a "java" package?

Tags: java

In Java, core or most used types are in packages named "java.lang" or "java.util" or etc. But there is nothing called a "java" package. To me, it makes sense to put at least the "java.lang" types in a package called "java". So, why isn't there a package called "java"?

Comment: I don't think anyone other than the origional Java authors can really answer that.  I suspect it's because "Everything can be filed under miscellaneous".  A "java" package doesn't really tell you anything about what does or should go in it and the Java authors always tried to push for meaningful package names.

Comment: This link may be relevant : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions

Comment: How is this question "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions"? @Mureinik

Comment: @theD because questions of the form "why did the creators of X not do Y" will usually be subject to opinion unless there is some easily searchable documentation on the subject.

Comment: Searchable doc on the subject! Don't these searches usually lead to Stackoverflow? Don't you think that Stackoverflow is a big enough community which includes the legends of the craft? @couling

Comment: Remove on hold. This question is targeted towards most experienced people. @Mureinik

Comment: The `java` package is more of a folder/collection of all Java core packages, than an actual package. Similarly, `javax` is a collection of all Java extension packages (although some became core without being moved). Same for your own packages, e.g. both `com` and `com.google` are organizational names, not really packages, but contains packages such as `guava`, `gwt`, and `android`.

Comment: `java.Object`? why not just `Object` :) ok ok, unnamed package is bad...

Comment: @theD The answer probably isn't documented anywhere. If it is then it may only be in private emails -"not searchable". Without documentation only the original architect could answer this. Even if James Gosling reads this question amongst the millions of java questions on net; decision may not have been a concious one. So all answers you will get will (99.9%) probably be conjecture. Such answers cause a lot of miss-information to proliferate across the web.  So SO take action to close such questions in order to reduce the noise.  The question has been flagged by experienced people correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There can be any number of reasons, but the most concise reason is that the developers chose not to create one.

I know that the official [convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) is that the package name should be the internet domain of the support for that project.

Maybe they chose not to create one because that would be unnecessarily confusing. Additionally, package names that are of the type `package` and not `location.package` are less clear.

Comment: We sometimes miss the birds eye view. It makes sense to name packages in my company like com.thed.X etc. But for the core packages we do not need them. Because name collision is automatically prevented. So, Why would the designers choose something like this? One explanation could be consistency. I asked this question just to get a confirmation. And these bojos have put it on hold!

Comment: @theD If I may be so bold... perhaps you're trying to ask a very different question. You appear to be saying you believe package naming is only about avoiding name collisions, but you can find evidence of them not being used this way.  To ask your question you might mention this and then lead into asking... have you missed something? ... are they used for something other than avoiding name collisions? ... what is best practice for company wide common code?

This is a good read for even for very experienced developers (http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: I think we miss the birds eye view oftentimes because we are conditioned to miss it!

Comment: Not really. Its difficult to see what you mean by birds eye view in this case.  Part of writing good questions is making sure you ask them at the level you want the answer.  If you ask a very specific question hoping to get a more general answer then you will be sadly disappointed.

Comment: Consider this. Package names should be `who.what`.  The What is the most important. The Who just avoids confusion with other developers.  Your example above is very bad practice.  Without the What you're effectively filing things under "Miscellaneous". Everything could be filed there.  Also as your company grows a single shared "common" package will become impractical.  Also package names let a person see at a glance the subject matter of a class to disambiguate between two or more classes.  Perhaps the answer to your question lies in the use of `java` as the Who not the What.